# Detecting MySQL querycache nativedriver from php

Tags: php, mysql

i need to detect from php if mysql query cache plugin is installed, any idea?
http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQLnd_Query_Cache_Plugin_for_PHP
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering this is a PHP extension, you could use the [**`extension_loaded()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php) function to check if its loaded.

If its name is `mysql_qc`, you could use :

```
if (extension_loaded('mysql_qc')) {
    // its is loaded, use it
}
```

Else, you could use [**`function_exists()`**][2], to check if one of the functions it exports exists.

For example, to check if the `mysqlnd_qc_get_cache_info()` function exists :

```
if (function_exists('mysqlnd_qc_get_cache_info')) {
    // That function exists, use it
}
```

Note that the second solution will return true even if that function has been created on the PHP-side, and not exported by an extension.

So, if you want to know if an extension is enabled, the first solution is the one you should use -- after all, that's why it exists.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way of checking if an extension is loaded that I've never used before is to view phpinfo in a web browser as you will also be shown all related variables for that extension and often you'll find something that needs tweaking.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If, I'm familiar with the extension and its options then I just check the list of installed extensions from the command line

```
php -m
```